# When does a rate-limit day start and end?

Tags: support, api, rate-limit

After reading the docs/faqs, I couldn't help but wonder...

What exactly **is** a day?

- When does it start?
- When does it end?
- What timezone are you using?

In other words, when my app runs out of requests for the day, at exactly what time will it be able to make requests again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the API, the day ends 24 hours after your first API call.

> A single IP address can only make a
>   limited number of requests per day to
>   the API. This limit is determined at
>   first request time, and is dependent
>   upon the presence of an API key.

Comment: This is correct; an IP will receive (upon the next request) a new request quota 24 hours after the previous quota was issued.

Comment: Your first ever request or your first request since not making any requests for over 24 hours?

Comment: Was this quote "quoted" from a specific page?  I can't find the 2nd half of this statement in writing anywhere.  (Also I'm wondering if it would be the same regardless of whether I use a key/token with the request as opposed to calling the API anonymously?)

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it's the start of the day, GMT like everything else on the sites, can't confirm this though.  For me, that would be 8PM EST (-4 hours) at the moment.

**Suggestion here:** If this isn't the case, I believe it should be.

The most likely alternative is that I'm wrong and it's a 24 hour cache expiration on an item that gets cached your first request, meaning it would completely depend upon when your first request was the previous day.

Comment: I assume this answer's incorrect and the other is correct?  (I'm not sure that the other answer is correct, I'm just assuming so because it has more votes and has a quote-block, lol)